# How to keep state when switch the component in Reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {stories: []};
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        $.get(Api.getList(), (result) => {
            const data = result;
            if (data) {
                this.setState((prevState) => ({
                    stories: data.stories
                }));
            }
        });
    }

    render() {
        if (this.state.stories.length == 0) {
            return (
                <Tpl>
                    <Loading/>
                </Tpl>
            );
        } else {
            return (
                <Tpl>
                    <Stories stories={this.state.stories}/>
                </Tpl>
            );
        }
    }
}
```

and everytime when I switch to this component, 
it will run `constructor` first. 
so the state will be empty.

what I want is if `stories` had items, it don't need to get data again.

is it any method to keep that state?

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to achieve this would be to use `react-redux` whereby you have a centralized store which maintains state to all the components and thus saving it from refreshing everytime the component loads

**[Here](https://www.codementor.io/reactjs/tutorial/intro-to-react-redux-pros)**  is a good article to help you get started with redux.

The other way to do what you want is to have you states saved in `localStorage` whereby on every component load you load data from `localStorage` and set to state initially and when updating a state also update the value there. Below is a sample method that you can follow for this approach.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    var stories = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem( 'stories' )) || null
    this.state = {stories: stories};
}
componentDidMount() {

        $.get(Api.getList(), (result) => {
            const data = result;
            if (data) {
               JSON.stringify(localStorage.setItem( 'stories', data.stories));
               this.setState((prevState) => ({
                    stories: data.stories
                }));
            }
        });
    }
```